# Winning criterion tag request: [minimum-distinct-chars]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, winning-criteria

There are several questions where the challenge is to accomplish a task with the least distinct characters - [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230024/minimal-distinct-character-quine), [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233591/make-a-gui-window-in-any-language-using-minimum-different-characters), [Possibly example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness/). There's probably more, these are hard to find.

Currently, these questions are all tagged with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), but it would be nice to have this as an explicit winning criterion.

[minimum-distinct-chars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimum-distinct-chars) is what I have so far, so name suggestions welcome.

Name suggestions welcome!

Pxeger, Wheat Wizard and PyGamer0 have [had some  ideas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/winning-criterion-name-ideas-for-meta-post), what're* your thoughts?

* if that's not a word, it is now.

Comment: I can also see plenty of challenges for the *maximum* number of distinct bytes, basically the bowling version of this. Might it actually be a better idea to just have a [tag:distinct-characters] or [tag:distinct-scoring] and combine it with either [tag:code-golf] or [tag:code-bowling] depending on which.  This would widen the net a little bit in terms of challenges, and the ideas are very similar.

Comment: @WheatWizard True. Why don't you write up an answer.

Comment: More examples :[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11336/56656), Similar scoring: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201650/hello-ascii-world), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69408/stop-internet-warming) (closed) and Related: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/encode-a-program-with-the-fewest-distinct-characters-possible)

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the minimum distinct character challenges linked it does seem like while there are a couple it's not a very well liked scoring criterion on it's own.

"Do X but with minimum characters" is just not interesting on it's own anymore.  Unlike other scoring criteria most challenges with this criterion end up feeling pretty much the same.

Of course [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) or other special rules could turn this on its head.  I just don't think we should anticipate a whole lot more of these challenges.

I still think that in the end the scant challenges we have may be worth tagging, but I think we can find a more useful tag by broadening the scope of this tag.

I suggest we add a single tag which just indicates that the scoring for the challenge involves the *distinct* characters rather than just all the characters.

[distinct-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinct-scoring)

So [distinct-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinct-scoring) + [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) would be minimum number of distinct characters, and [distinct-scoring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinct-scoring) + [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) would be the maximum number of distinct characters.

This widens the potential pool on the tag a bit to include more challenges which really are very similar.  It's also more open to variation which I think this type of challenge is in desperate need of if it is going to keep being asked.